# Javamail empty AUTH

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I send a mail via JavaMail SMTP to an Exchange server (version uknown). This works fine when testing from my local system

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "exchange.TLD.DOMAIN", port 25, isSSL false
220 *************************************************************************************
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "exchange.TLD.DOMAIN", port: 25

EHLO SERVER.TLD.DOMAIN
250-SERVER.TLD.DOMAIN Hello [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
250-SIZE 35840000
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-XXXXXXXA
250-AUTH NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 XXXXXXXB
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35840000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XXXXXXXA", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XXXXXXXB", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=exchange.TLD.DOMAIN, user=DOMAIN\USER, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: NTLM
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism NTLM
DEBUG NTLM: type 1 message: 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 01 00 00 00 03 B2 00 00 07 00 07 00 29 00 00 00 09 00 09 00 20 00 00 00 6C 6F 63 61 6C 68 6F 73 74 41 58 49 4D 41 44 45 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH NTLM command trace suppressed
DEBUG NTLM: type 3 message: 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 03 00 00 00 18 00 18 00 86 00 00 00 18 00 18 00 9E 00 00 00 0E 00 0E 00 40 00 00 00 26 00 26 00 4E 00 00 00 12 00 12 00 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B6 00 00 00 01 82 00 00 41 00 58 00 49 00 4D 00 41 00 44 00 45 00 73 00 61 00 70 00 2E 00 62 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 66 00 72 00 65 00 69 00 67 00 61 00 62 00 65 00 6C 00 6F 00 63 00 61 00 6C 00 68 00 6F 00 73 00 74 00 CA B8 9C 4A 27 9C 8E 1E 50 1B C5 3C 34 AE C1 9E 17 2B 74 C1 57 8D 18 B3 B1 EF DA 28 C1 87 A4 8A 9F 24 AB AA 9E 21 DB 07 AB F9 FC BD AF 50 05 16 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH NTLM succeeded
```

As soon as I deploy the software on a test system, sending the mail does not work anymore.

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "exchange.TLD.DOMAIN", port 25, isSSL false
220 CO-EX01.TLD.DOMAIN Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 8 Nov 2017 12:17:01 +0100
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "exchange.TLD.DOMAIN", port: 25

EHLO SERVER.TLD.DOMAIN
250-SERVER.TLD.DOMAIN Hello [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
250-SIZE
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250-XRDST
250 XSHADOW
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-ANONYMOUSTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XEXCH50", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XRDST", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XSHADOW", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=exchange.TLD.DOMAIN, user=DOMAIN\USER, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: NTLM
DEBUG SMTP: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
2017-11-08 12:17:02.445 ERROR [    scheduled-1] de.engie.ers.request.MailSender          : Error while sending email: 

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:847)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:748)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:252)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:174)
    at de.engie.ers.request.MailSender.sendRequests(MailSender.java:82)
    at de.engie.ers.common.Scheduler.sendRequests(Scheduler.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Mind the empty AUTH when using the software on the test system.
What am I missing here from JavaMail?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property [`mail.smtp.starttls.enable`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.starttls.enable) to true.

Or set [`mail.smtp.ssl.enable`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.ssl.enable) to true.

Make sure you're using a [current version of JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).